# How to Export All Daily Task State Changes to File?

Tags: org-mode, org-ql

I am trying to generate nice end-of-day reports in the file `diary.org` for logging and archiving purposes. I would like to generate a simple list of all TODO task state changes for the current day to be saved to `diary.org`, but I'm not sure how to get this data there automatically.

I am using org-log-done (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Closing-items.html), since I thought it'd help to have timestamps to search for the right data, and I also experimented with org-agenda-log-mode (see: https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html), but was unable to figure out how to export this data (and I would prefer simply exporting the time stamps and headings using org-log-done info anyway, as I already generate a daily clocktable and org-agenda-log-mode will then provide redundant information in a format I like less).

Lastly, I thought this link would help more, but I couldn't extract or assemble any specifically useful info for my case from it: https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html

Thank you in advance for any help.

*EDIT:*
In the mean time, I've developed a temporary work around by simply clocking in and out quickly whenever I change a task state, so that this information can be pulled by org-clock-report. A more elegant solution would probably involve using org-ql (see: https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql), but I've heard that persistently using logbooks or archiving "DONE" tasks might also achieve what I seek. For now, I like this solution.

Comment: Any updates? Have you found a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`org-ql` is now a good solution for this.  For example, here's a command that displays recent items, which you could easily adapt:

```
(cl-defun org-ql-agenda-recent-items (days &optional (type 'ts))
  "Show items from previous DAYS days with timestamps of TYPE.
TYPE may be `ts', `ts-active', `ts-inactive', `clocked',
`closed', `deadline', `planning', or `scheduled'."
  (interactive (list (read-number "Days: ")
                     (->> '(ts ts-active ts-inactive clocked closed deadline planning scheduled)
                          (completing-read "Timestamp type: ")
                          intern)))
  (let ((from (->> (ts-now)
                   (ts-adjust 'day (* -1 days))
                   (ts-apply :hour 0 :minute 0 :second 0)
                   ;; Formatting isn't required, but it looks better in the header than a struct.
                   ts-format)))
    (org-ql-search (org-agenda-files)
      `(,type :from ,from :to ,(ts-format (ts-now)))
      :title "Recent items"
      :sort '(date priority todo)
      :groups '((:todo "DONE")
                (:category "log" :tag "log")
                (:auto-parent t)
                (:auto-todo t)))))

;; Show entries with any timestamp from last 7 days:
(org-ql-agenda-recent-items 7)

;; Show entries clocked in last 7 days:
(org-ql-agenda-recent-items 30 'clocked)

;; Show entries closed in last 7 days:
(org-ql-agenda-recent-items 30 'closed)
```